# Shoot ball with rotation (transition)

Tags: coronasdk

I'm making a shooter-based game.
My shooter is in the middle of the screen, I can move the rotation of the shooter when touching the screen with the event.x , event.y, but there is my problem:
I want to make a button to shoot bullets from the shooter to the direction that the shooter is showing.
I know I can fix this problem with trigonometry, but I'm searching for an easier way.
Anyone knows how to do a transition with a rotation? 
Thank you,
Fannick

Comment: what have you tired so far?

Comment: Well for now nothing, I know it could be done with trigonometry, I'm just trying to figuring how to solve the problem, I imaginated to create an invisible circle, and the direction that the shooter is showing will be showed as a point on the circle to do the transition. (the circle is out of the screen actually, so from the center, with a radius of 250 for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So he it is! :) From an object in the middle, with the rotation of the object in degrees, it will define where the bullet will be shot with the transition to, note that "c" is the shooter, "h" the display.contentHeight and "w" the display.contentWidth. I also defined bulletX and bulletY as the second possition of the bullet.

```
    if c.rotation <= math.deg(math.atan((h/2)/(w/2))) and c.rotation >= 0 then
    bulletX = w
    bulletY = h/2 + w/2 * math.tan( (c.rotation * math.pi)/180 )

elseif c.rotation > math.tan(math.rad((h/2)/(w/2))) and c.rotation <= 90 then

    bulletX = w/2 + math.tan( (90 * math.pi) / 180  - (c.rotation * math.pi ) / 180) * h/2
    bulletY = h

elseif c.rotation > 90 and c.rotation <= 90 + math.deg( math.atan( (w/2) / (h/2) ) ) then

    bulletX = w/2 - math.tan( ((c.rotation * math.pi)/180) - ((90 * math.pi) / 180)) * h/2 
    bulletY = h

elseif c.rotation > 90 + math.deg( math.atan( (w/2) / (h/2) ) ) and c.rotation <= 180 then
    bulletX = 0
    bulletY = h/2 + math.tan( math.pi - ((c.rotation*math.pi) / 180)) * w/2

elseif c.rotation > 180 and c.rotation <= 180 + math.deg( math.atan ((h/2)/(w/2))) then
    bulletX = 0
    bulletY = h/2 - math.tan( ((c.rotation * math.pi)/180) - math.pi) * w/2

elseif c.rotation > 180 + math.deg( math.atan ((h/2)/(w/2))) and c.rotation <= 270 then
    bulletX = w/2 - math.tan( ((270 * math.pi) / 180) - ((c.rotation * math.pi) / 180)) * h/2
    bulletY = 0

elseif c.rotation > 270 and c.rotation <= 270 + math.deg(math.atan((w/2)/(h/2))) then
    bulletX = w/2 + math.tan( ((c.rotation * math.pi)/180) - ((270 * math.pi)/180)) * h/2
    bulletY = 0

elseif c.rotation > 270 + math.deg(math.atan((w/2)/(h/2))) and c.rotation <= 360 then
    bulletX = w
    bulletY = h/2 - math.tan( ((360 * math.pi)/180) - ((c.rotation * math.pi) / 180) ) * w/2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't know right now if there is a possibility to pull this off without trigonometry (and I am in a hurry so I don't really have the time to think one up), but even if there was I highly doubt that would make the process any easier.

"sin" and "cos" are two functions that seem quite intimidating to a beginner, especially in such a context, but honestly, they're quite tame. Best thing you can do is go online and search for some explanations for trigonometry functions (some university professors publish their lecture documents, and usually do a good job at explaining it to beginners who have just started their studies) and you'll get the hang of it quite quickly. As knowing how to applying this knowledge to further problems can prove to be very useful later on, finding a "workaround" for not having to use trigonometry is simply not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Corona physics module. It will probably be easier and you can even have collision detection easily implemented if you need it too.
Have a look at those links :

- [Physics engine tutorial](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-box2d-physics-engine)
- [Physics engine API documentation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/)

With the physic engine you just have to set the gravity to 0, add your bullet to the physic engine with addBody() and then apply an impulse to the bullet to make it move in the direction you want(your target) with applyLinearImpulse().